# How to make my Laravel API project with Passport faster?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm developing a Laravel API based on [larapi project](https://github.com/esbenp/larapi) and I think I'm doing something wrong, because every request to my API takes about 3 seconds to return, don't matter the size of the response.

I've searched a lot and already tried to run the following commands, but my requests still slow:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

My server and database server are hosted separatedly. I already did some tests with other projects and the servers runs fast. It seems to be a problem with Passport (Laravel OAuth authentication), it try to authenticate the user's access token on every request.

Has anyone faced this problem?

Thanks for your attenion.
Regards.

Comment: Is it happening when you log in or not using the token??

Comment: Hi Abir, it happens on login and on other requests, since requests to get basic user information until requests to get more of 500 rows for datatables. Every request is taking about 3 seconds to return.

Comment: is your backend server and DB server hosted in the same VPC? Are they hosted in the same region?

Comment: Yes, they are hosted in the same VPC.